# Reading numbers from a txt file in batch

Tags: batch-file

I am making a script to keep track of my grades. It is just a simple beginner script which I am making for myself, and am doing so because I am interested learning batch programming.

So far my script allows me to choose to add numbers to a .txt file. I have also made it display the numbers in the window. I would also like it to read the numbers from the file, and do some math with them, but can't figure out how to read the numbers

Answer (score 0):

Well this litle function can read the line you what from your txt file

```
:_ReadLine
REM %~1 txt file, %~2 the line you want to read, %~3 the variable you wish to give.
for /f "usebackq skip=%~2 delims=" %%a in ("%~1") do set "%~3=%%a" & goto :EOF
```

you can call it like this :

```
call :_ReadLine "test.txt" "21" "test"
```

this will read 21. line of your test.txt file and add it to test variable

**EDIT**

You didnt give any example about your txt file so i assumed its something like this:

```
10
20
30
40
50
60
```

if you call this function like;

```
call :_ReadLine "yourFileName.txt" "5" "test"
```

This will read line number `5` and set its value to `%test%` if you are working inside of `EnableDelayedExpansion` use `!` instead of `%` like `!test!`

in the end you can use this variable for whatever you want to. For example `echo %test%` will give you result of `50`

Comment: Could you explain a little better what the different types of comments are? Like what i am supposed to fill into the different places. Pretty new to this... Didn't get it to work btw, so that's why i'm asking!

Comment: Your script will never read line 1. `%~2` represents the number of lines to skip, and FOR /F does not allow a SKIP value of 0. If you don't want to skip a line than you must leave off the SKIP option.